# Under China's two-child policy, what happens if triplets are born?

Tags: china

China has had a one-child policy until 2015 and now has a two-child policy intended to decrease the population size. What happens if multiple children are born at once, as is the case for twins (under the one-child policy) or triplets (under the two-child policy)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The report [out there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-child_policy#Twins) is that the (former) policy does not count the number of infants produced, it counts the number of giving births.

Comment: Somehow I missed that the one-child policy was phased out in favor of a two-child policy. I've updated my question to cover both.

Comment: But also, the point was that the policy does not distinguish between giving birth to one child and giving birth to twins or triplets.